# Registering custom control in web.config fails. Why?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, custom-controls

I have a class deriving from Control and am trying to register it in the web.config file like this:

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="prefix1" tagName="tag1" src="~/Controls/Class1.cs" namespace="theNamespace" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

But when I write the following in the markup:

```
<prefix1:tag1></prefix1:tag1>
```

I get an error:

> Unrecognized namespace 'prefix1'.

Why?

**EDIT**

Somehow, when it's a "user control" it works, but when it's a simple cs file such as [the last post here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1218582.aspx)  - it fails.

Answer (score 1):

When you are registering custom controls, you will need to refer to the assembly that contains the control, and not the actual source file.

So it should look somewhat like this:

```
<add tagPrefix="prefix1" namespace="The.Name.Space" assembly="TheNameOfTheAssembly"/>
```

For more details, you can ready [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/11/14/register_custom_controls_in_web.config.aspx/) by Phil Haack.

Comment: Thanks. But I tried that too. (It's the assembly of the solution.) Didn't help.